# In ANDROID which function will be used instead of UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {})?

Tags: android

UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {})

**How can I change this function into an android??**

Comment: Please provide more details on the background of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of would be: Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action)

Comment: Thank u! Ths answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are in the code. In a View, you can use `post(new Runnable() {...});` You can also create a `Handler` object and use its `post()` method; you just need access to the Handler object.